# Newbie to Javascript: iOS, Android, or Desktop Javascript Optimization

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I have recently been getting into Javascript. Not a lot, but I'd like optimization and tips on if there'd be a better way to handle this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fnIsAppleMobile() 
    {
       if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent != null) 
       {
        var strUserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var arrMatches = strUserAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
        var arrMatches2 = strUserAgent.match(/(android)/);
        if (arrMatches) {
             document.write("<b>You are on iOS!</b>"); }
        else if (arrMatches2) {
             document.write("<b>You are on Android!</b>"); }
        else { 
             document.write("<b>You are likely on a computer.</b>")}
       }
    }

var bIsAppleMobile = fnIsAppleMobile();
</script>
```

The way this script ends cannot be optimal. Any advice?

Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: First of all you might want to elaborate why that script cannot be optimal?

Answer (score 1):

A `function` as you use it, should return a value. In this case I might thing you're expecting a boolean to be more specific.

You could improve your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnIsAppleMobile() 
{
   var blnReturn = false;

   if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent != null) 
   {
    var strUserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var arrMatches = strUserAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (arrMatches) {
         blnReturn = true;
    }
   }

   // True if this is Apple Mobile; false if it's something 
   return blnReturn;
}

// Store it in a variable
var bIsAppleMobile = fnIsAppleMobile();

// Or use it directly where you need it:
if (fnIsAppleMobile()) {
    alert("Cool gadget");
}
</script>
```

My advise; never use `document.write`. Not when you're dealing with a [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) at least.
If you need to output some text, try to output it as text inside a DOM node.